# sql query contains certain words of selected column

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help I wanna write a script that contains certain word.
e.g:

```
 table name : sample
 +-------+-------+
 |column1|column2|
 +-------+-------+
 |1      |help   |
 +-------+-------+

table name : sample2
+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
|1      |help me|
+-------+-------+
```

I try write a script like this:

```
SELECT *FROM SAMPLE S
JOIN SAMPLE2 S2 ON S.COLUMN1 = S2.COLUMN2
WHERE S.COLUMN2 LIKE S2.COLUMN2
```

but the "where clause" is does not work
any one know how to write the correct script?
if any please answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This where clause should ideally be part of the JOIN.

You need to prefix and suffix the wildcard % using string concatenation in order for the like to work:

```
SELECT *FROM
SAMPLE S JOIN SAMPLE2 S2
ON S.COLUMN1 = S2.COLUMN1
And S2.COLUMN2 LIKE '%' || S.COLUMN2 || '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the join condition so they are both using `COLUMN1` and then you want the to match:

```
'help me' LIKE '%help%'
```

So:

```
SELECT *
FROM   SAMPLE S
       JOIN SAMPLE2 S2
       ON (   S.COLUMN1 = S2.COLUMN1
          AND S2.COLUMN2 LIKE '%' || S.COLUMN2 || '%' )
```